# Runtime error while running a Spring Session + Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc-test, spring-session

I am trying to run this [Spring Session example available here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/archive/1.0.0.RELEASE.zip) but, I've used Maven instead of Gradle. I get the following error both while a) Running the WAR file and b) Deploying the WAR in an WildFly8.2 server

A quick search suggests that the problem could be conflicting versions among various dependencies quoted in the pom.xml.

> What is the root cause & solution for this error ?

***Error while Running or Deploying the WAR***

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:381)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:274)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:25)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:377)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.asUnmodifiableOrderedSet(SpringApplication.java:1031)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getListeners(SpringApplication.java:930)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.<init>(EventPublishingRunListener.java:47)
    ... 16 more
```

***Here is my complete POM.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <!-- ... -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <!-- ... -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<!--           <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>   -->          
        </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> -->


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>   

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orange.redis-embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>


       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: That exception means you have mixed dependency versions. Don't specify your own versions for the dependencies Spring will pull in, and use Spring IO if you need additional Spring components not included.

Comment: @chrylis are you saying that for all the Spring group dependencies, i better remove the version ?

Comment: @chrylis I've removed the version number for all the Spring group dependencies except the "spring-session-data-redis". If i do not mention a version for this i am getting maven build error stating that i should mention the version for this. But, if i give a version only for this and generate the WAR, i still keep getting the above said original error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see a few places for cleanup:

- You have conflicting Spring versions in your pom. Specifically spring-web-4.1.3 is explicitly listed and Spring Boot 1.1.10 brings in Spring 4.0.8. Remove every version from your pom (except Spring Session & embedded-redis) which are not yet managed by Spring Boot) and let the spring-boot-starter-parent manage it
- Remove the spring-web dependency all together (it is already included in spring-boot-starter-web)
- Replace the security dependencies with spring-boot-starter-security

You can find the summary below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <!-- ... -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <!-- ... -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
          <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.orange.redis-embedded</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: One note here - you are using com.orange.redis-embedded, which is a fork of an original embedded-redis project:
https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis